# PHP Log user out completely

Tags: php

I want to log a user out when they click on the log out link and it works but there is a problem . When I click the log out link the user gets logged out and goes to the header page but if I click the back button I go right back into the previous page without logging in again and this isn't safe . When the user logs out I want them to be logged out completely and the only way to get back in is by signing in . Can someone help ?

```
<?php    
include("connect.php");

//check if form is submitted
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || 
     ! isset($_POST['signin'])) 
{
    // looks like a hack, send to index.php
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

if (empty($_POST["usernam"])) {
    echo 'fill in username to sign in';
}
if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {
    echo 'fill in password to sign in';
}

$sql = "SELECT pw FROM users WHERE usernam = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
if ( !$stmt ) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['pw']);
$stmt->execute();

if ( !$stmt ) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
// we found a row with that username, 
// now we need to check the password is correct

// get the password from the row
$stmt->bind_result($hashed_pwd);
$stmt->fetch();

if ( password_verify($_POST['pw'], $hashed_pwd) ) {
    // password verified
            header('Location: home.php');
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or Password. <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br />';
}

?>
```

logout.php

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:index.php');
```

process2.php(login):

```
include("connect.php");

  //check if form is submitted
  if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || 
     ! isset($_POST['signin'])) 
   {
    // looks like a hack, send to index.php
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
  }

  if (empty($_POST["usernam"])) {
    echo 'fill in username to sign in';
  }
  if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {
    echo 'fill in password to sign in';
   }

  $sql = "SELECT pw FROM users WHERE usernam = ?";

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
  if ( !$stmt ) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
  }

  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['pw']);
  $stmt->execute();

  if ( !$stmt ) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
  }
  // we found a row with that username, 
  // now we need to check the password is correct

  // get the password from the row
  $stmt->bind_result($hashed_pwd);
  $stmt->fetch();

  if ( password_verify($_POST['pw'], $hashed_pwd) ) {
    // password verified
            header('Location: home.php');
  } else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or Password. <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br />';
  }
```

Comment: Well how you do this REALLY DOES depend on how you  keep track of logged in users. Show some code from your login script and that should give us a few clues

Comment: Are you using a session?

Comment: I'll update my question

Comment: there's only the one page of code here. If the others haven't started the session etc. we don't know that. There isn't even any session here period.

Comment: Well this does not tell us how you keep track of logged in users I am afraid.

Comment: *"When I click the log out link the user gets logged out"* - where's that? and the form for this.

Comment: @Fabio I dont think the password is plain text, look a little closer

Comment: Do you have some code in every page that checks if a user is logged in? **If not then the login process appears to be there just for show**. So the logout porcess must also be there just for show. Your pages do not check if a user is logged in therefore logging out has no effect

Comment: you need to check for session, in your file, and if its not set, than dont let the user see the page

Comment: If your logout page doesn't destroy the session (if you're using them), then there you go. Your question's unclear and I for one won't be offering further help until I know/see exactly what we're dealing with here. I have moved on, good luck with this.

Comment: Can you show us the LOGOUT script as well

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

On the previous page (and all other pages that require login) you need to add a condition that checks if the user is logged in (i.e. if the session variable for user login is set). That will display the content only if the user is logged in.

Let me elaborate this a little and help you with an example:

`index.php`

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "Welcome to my website! You are logged in.";
    // do stuff...
else {
    header("Location: login.php"); // redirects user to login page if the username session variable is not set
}
```

`home.php` and all other pages should work based on the same concept as above:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "page when user is logged in";
    // do stuff...
else {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Then you need to add the session variable to the code block inside your login page where it checks if the password is correct and the user is logged in:

```
session_start();
// ... (your other code) ...
if ( password_verify($_POST['pw'], $hashed_pwd) ) {
    // password verified
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["usernam"];
    header('Location: home.php');
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or Password. <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br />';
}
```

Finally, your `logout.php` page should also unset that variable once called:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    session_destroy();
    echo "succesfully logged out!";
    header('refresh:5;location:index.php'); // redirect to index.php in 5 seconds 
}
else {
    echo "you are not logged in!";
}
```

Using `session_destroy()` only is not enough as the session variables are somehow still set after destroying the session. See the first example of [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#example-3902).

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I can't see why Brian's answer is being downvoted, given the very limited details/code in the question. This IMHO, does somewhat answer the question.

Comment: @Fabio it's an ambiguous answer to an ambiguous question. Besides that, my current reputation does not allow me to comment on other posts.

Comment: I agree with Fred... The question does not allow you to answer better than this. Firstly, you cannot see that mkd is using sessions or not... we don't know how the users are logged in, how can we know how to log them out?

Comment: I know you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
 and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: I'm pretty sure the asker does not really know how to work with sessions, hence I added some examples to my answer.

Comment: Your edits are quite confusing... The first block you posted is the same as the last one? Is that the same page? Try to follow the example I posted and test it.